# Deploying spring app in Tomcat with Mongodb running in Micro cloud foundry

Tags: spring, mongodb, cloud-foundry

I am getting the following exception when trying to connect Micro cloud foundry Mongodb server 
through Spring Application running inside localhost Tomcat server.

```
Exception:
Jun 05, 2012 4:30:44 PM com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector fetchMaxBsonObjectSize
WARNING: Exception determining maxBSON size using0
java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [/192.168.80.128:27017] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:228)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:93)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.findOne(DBPort.java:146)
```

Scenario:

Spring app configured for Cloud foundry which works in Micro cloud foundry set up.
It also works when deployed to Live cloudfoundry.com 
I deployed the app in VMWare Vfabric Tomcat inside Spring tool suite(STS), 
pointing the mongodb running in my Virtual machine ( 192.168.80.128)

Root-context.xml: (with the change in the host configuration)

```
<beans profile="default">
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="pwdtest" host="192.168.80.128" 
port="27017" username="test_user" password="efgh"/>
</beans
```

This host is pinging from the localhost machine.

Please advice what needs to be changed in the mongodb setup.

I couldn't find through the god site.. I mean google..:)

Cheers
Kum

Comment: What version of MongoDB is this? It looks like it may be an older version that the Java driver is having issues negotiating a connection with.

Comment: I am using the latest version from micro cloudfoundry setup. As I mentioned, it works with the same version when I deploy my app in MicroCloudFoundry and LiveCloudFoundry.

Answer (score 1):

If the Tomcat application is not running on the Micro Cloundfoundry VM then it will not be able to access the MongoDB instance via the port 27017 thats only a available via localhost on the VM itself.

If the application is running outside the MCF VM then you will need to create a tunnel to that instance using VMC and then adjust the connection in your application accordingly. For more details on "vmc tunnel" take a look at http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html

Cheers

Dan

Comment: Do you must have use vmc for using mongodb on cloudfoundry?